# scp/rsync autocomplete works one way but not the other

Tags: bash, rsync, scp

I have two machines, laptop and server. Both of them source `/etc/bash_completion` in `.bashrc`.

What works:

```
server$ scp file laptop:~/stage/[tab][tab]
server$ scp laptop:~/stage/[tab][tab] .
server$ rsync -r folder laptop:~/stage/[tab][tab]
```

What doesn't work

```
laptop$ scp file server:/data/[tab][tab]
laptop$ scp server:/data/[tab][tab] .
laptop$ rsync -r folder server:/data/[tab][tab]
```

The laptop is running ubuntu 16.04 and the server is running 18.04.

### server

rsync version 3.1.2

scp/ssh don't take --version

### laptop

rsync version 3.1.1

scp/ssh don't take --version

Both machines have the other's public key, and ssh (as well as actual rsync/scp transfers) work without password. Clearly everything is set up as it works one way, but I can't figure out what would be causing it to fail in the other direction?

Comment: I can reproduce this on Debian. Looking at the `/usr/share/doc/bash-completion/changelog.Debian.gz` file, I have 1:2.1-4.3 for the one that completes but only 1:2.0-1 for the one that doesn't. If you get a similar difference it may simply be that the newer version completes more accurately.

Comment: That directory doesn't exist on laptop - which prompted me to check, `/etc/bash_completion` doesn't exist either - I'm missing a package. What do I have to install on the laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution - `bash-completion` package was never installed on the laptop.

It's a misleading issue, because in `.bashrc` the source of the file is correct, and it doesn't throw an error. However the file never existed.

The bashrc does check, however for /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion which does exist. Why it doesn't work, I don't know.

`sudo apt install bash-completion` fixes the issue.